# Lattice Desargues Configuration

Tags: geometry, triangles, integer-lattices

Here's a [Desargues Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem) with all points on a square lattice:

[image]

Is there a more compact version, either on a square lattice or triangular lattice?  Also, if there a less obvious Desargues configuration that's larger, but still with relatively simple coordinates?

Comment: Why larger ? Do you mean that you want a configuration still with integer coordinates but with absence of any parallelism ?

Comment: Yes, all the parallels makes this one perhaps a bit inelegant.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/653018/305862).